# Selecting a constexpr index from a dynamic index

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I have C++ code that calls some SSE/AVX functions taking immediate index values (e.g. [`int _mm_extract_epi16 (__m128i a, int imm8)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_extract_epi16&expand=5291,3678,4065,333,254,2420)). The problem is, that I don't know the index value at compile time, so I have to do a dynamic `int` to `constexpr int` conversion:

```
template <int index>
auto extract(__m128i a) noexcept
{
    static_assert(index < 8, "index must be less than 8");
    return _mm_extract_epi16(a, index);
}

auto extract(const __m128i a, const int index) noexcept
{
    switch (index) {
        case 0:  return extract<0>(a);
        case 1:  return extract<1>(a);
        case 2:  return extract<2>(a);
        case 3:  return extract<3>(a);
        case 4:  return extract<4>(a);
        case 5:  return extract<5>(a);
        case 6:  return extract<6>(a);
        case 7:  return extract<7>(a);
        default: return extract<7>(a);
    }
}
```

I'm upgrading my code-base to AVX2 and AVX-512 (and therefore extending the number of cases to 16 and 32, respectively), and started wondering if there was a better way to do this? Or at-least a way that avoids so much typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
auto extract(const __m128i a, const int index, std::index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept
{
    if(index < 8 && index >= 0)
    {
        decltype(extract<0>(a)) r;
        int unused[] = {(index == Is ? (r = extract<Is>(a), 0) : 0)...};
        (void)unused;
        return r;
    }
    else
        return extract<7>(a);
}

auto extract(const __m128i a, const int index) noexcept
{
    return extract(a, index, std::make_index_sequence<8>{});
}
```

Or you could use fold expressions in C++17 instead. This compiles down to the [same thing](https://godbolt.org/z/13DLqw) as a switch.

I would however argue that in this case, since all you are saving is some typing, just copying and pasting would be fine. It is simpler to read and write.